# Lightning Web Component Base Component Documentation

Tags: documentation

I have been googling and digging around in documentation for about 30 minutes. I'm trying to find documentation on the base components for LWC.

This is the closest thing I found: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_map_aura_lwc_components.html

I'm looking for something more like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm where it lists the components attributes and stuff.

I understand that there is some level of parity to Lightning components and that I can use the first doc to help identify differences, but I'd like something specific to LWC so that I don't have to dig around in several documents to try to  piece together a working knowledge.

As an aside, I went to the auradocs from my instance, and I get errors when navigating around (for instance, when viewing the button component). Some components also appear to be missing from the aura docs (my docs don't show me the datatable component).

The question is, is there good, complete, documentation for the LWC base components? Or what other options do I have for reliable documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took entirely too long and I found it by looking for aura documentation but this does appear to be what I was looking for: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/

Comment: Yes, that's the new official documentation. Auradocs I believe has been deprecated. You can also use the "link to your org" option in the new page to view your custom components in the documentation.